# Select text from GridPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have this very simple example of GridPane.

```
    GridPane playerGrid = new GridPane();

    Text title = new Text("Top Scorers in English Premier League");
    title.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
    playerGrid.add(title, 0,0,4,1);
```

How I can select the text with the mouse and copy it when the program is running?

Answer (score 6):

[Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) nodes in JavaFX are not selectable.

If you want to have text selectable, use a selection aware control.

The fact that the text is eventually placed in a [GridPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) is irrelevant to this question.

[image: selectabletext]

For example, use a read only [TextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SelectableTextSample extends Application {
    @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(
            new Scene(
                new SelectableText(
                    "Top Scorers in English Premier League"
                )
            )
        );
        stage.show();
    }

    class SelectableText extends TextField {
        SelectableText(String text) {
            super(text);
            setEditable(false);
            setPrefColumnCount(20);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Alternate solution*

You could use a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) if you wish.  For some situations that may be a better solution, but for others it may not.

Comment: I have no idea what "not very good" means. Edit your question to more accurately explain, your requirements, desires and progress.